# Reproducible command calls

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm hoping to improve my record keeping for various computer experiments.

What would be useful is a single command which records to a folder, the command used, any arguments and any files accessed. Such that that command can be rerun at any future point in time or the specific input inspected.

I imagine that to do this will require redirecting read/write requests in an dynamic fashion and probably be impossible for it to be transparent and thus it would end up something like containers...

I am wondering if this exists already and I just haven't heard of it before or if there is some os level limitation preventing such a program.

Comment: `script` perhaps?

Comment: @roaima that looks like one half of it! Thanks! But it won't record file accesses...

Comment: A VM with a rollback snapshot point?

Comment: `strace` perhaps?

Comment: Look at the source of `installwatch`. It shows how to intercept system calls.